# Generating client stubs from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, webservices-client

I am starting on a new project with commercial vendor. I need to write an integration module in our application to consume commercial vendor's web service. So, WSDL is not controlled by us.

I think the general approach is to do a "Contract First" development and generate stubs from the WSDL file. I would like to know what technologies are available to do this? I would really like the simplest approach that works. We use Maven 3.0.3 and Spring 3.0.5 extensively. Can I use Spring WebServiceTemplate?

Please let me know if the question isn't clear or additional details are needed.

Thanks,
Tapasvi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the java stubs with the [maven plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) for [JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/). Then you can use the stubs in [spring](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/) to expose them as a webservice. Luckily, it's quite simple :).

Just a suggestion, don't re-generate the stubs every time you build the project, as (obviously) you won't be able to add any code to the stubs, which is sometimes **very** useful. I made this mistake long time ago and it was quite painful, because I had to put code in places where it didn't belong. In the last few years I used a maven profile to generate the stubs on demand and then I merged them "manually" to add the extra code. Of course, this is only viable if the WSDL doesn't change very often.

Comment: Just to leave my feedback, this is the approach (using maven plugin for JAX-WS) I used and am very happy with the way it works.

Answer (score 4):

I have used axis and the easiest way to do is to run the utility wsdl2java and pass the location of the webservice along with the ?wdsl option.

I know lots of IDE's these days will allow to generate you stubs from within. MyeclipseIDE has an option to ingest an WSDL so does intelliJ. I think the safer approach is to use wsdl. Also if you are using jax-ws you can try

wsimport -keep -verbose location to wsdl

Comment: Eclipse JEE supports Axis too.

Answer (score 4):

JAX-WS is included in the standard Java 6 distribution making it very simple to use.

Generate stubs with `wsimport` in the JDK (remember to enable as many warnings as possible, as  you want to know anything that may cause problems).